# Django REST Framework Browsable API JWT Auth

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to integrate the django-rest-framework-simplejwt package for jwt auth.
Everything works as expected, the only issues is that I don't know how to make it work with the Django Rest Framework Interface.

When I try to access a "protected" view I get the expected Not Authorized response, but there is no way for me to add the token when making the request.

And when I try to Login I get redirected to the django login, which doesn't help.

How can I add the Bearer token to the Django Rest Framework Interface?
To circumvent this, I've installed the drf_spectacular package that does its job very well, I am just curios if I can make the Django Rest Framework Interface work with the jwt token so that I don't need the drf_spectacular package.

Some of my configs:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "corsheaders",
    "rest_framework",
    "rest_framework_simplejwt",
    "drf_spectacular",
    "todo_api",
]    

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": ("rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated",),
        "DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS": "drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema",
        "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
            "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication",
        ),
    }

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

#TODOListApiView.py
    from .serializers import TodoSerializer
    from drf_spectacular.utils import extend_schema
    from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication
    
    
    class TodoListApiView(APIView):
        # add permission to check if user is authenticated
        authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
        permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
        ...
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: There is a Log In link at the top right. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: So that login link redirects me to a form and after login the token is still not added a.k.a I still don’t have the jet token in the request header.

Answer (score 1):

The Browsable API uses SessionAuthentication by default. Adding "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication" to your "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES" should do the trick.

Comment: This worked for me thank you 

Does this open the APIs up to any security vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 0):

Aparently its not possible and you need to use a chrome extension such as "ModHeader" to add the jwt token to the header in the browser.

A shame, you would expect these libraries to make compatible implementations with each other.